# How can I assign an argument of type 'Function' to a parameter of type 'void Function()'?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a stateless widget like this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Answers extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function nextQuestion;

  Answers(this.nextQuestion);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: nextQuestion,
      child: Text("Answer"),    
    );
  }
}
```

However, an error appears in the `onPressed` argument: "The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'". How can I solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57761489/error-the-argument-type-future-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-void)

Answer (score 7):

Just change the type of `nextQuestion` to `void Function()`:

```dart
final void Function() nextQuestion;
```

Answer (score 0):

changing

```
  final Function nextQuestion;
```

to

```
final VoidCallback nextQuestion;
```

This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change type of nextQuestion to VoidCallback which can be used if you have a function which returning no data with no arguments.
change your datatype from Function to VoidCallback.

final VoidCallback nextQuestion;

```
       or you can put anonymous function in front of onPressed (){}
```

onPressed: ()=>nextQuestion,